# Create action script to filter table data using drop down list in html from pandas

Tags: javascript, python, html, pandas

I have a python script that converts a given dataframe to html. Now that if I want to add drop down list in html file to filter data based on a column. How would I achieve it from python pandas script ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please give more detail about your web framework. You can perform this operation in many why.

Comment: I have no idea on web framework.I will have to prepare dataframe in pandas script and convert it to html file. the html file will have drop down to filter & render data based on it.